# How to discard scanf errors and identifying highest prime number from 4 input integers using multi threading

Tags: c, multithreading, scanf, primes, lcm

I am solving a question to calculate LCM and highest prime number from a set of 4 integers. I have trouble solving exceptions w.r.t scanf such as

1. some inputs are not integers
2. if there are more/less than 4 inputs
3. if inputs not entered with commas or
4. if there is no prime number from input

I tried using the following code:

```
if((scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &num1,&num2,&num3,&num4))!=4) /* for 4 input verification */

if((scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &num1,&num2,&num3,&num4))<4) /* for non-integer inputs */

if((scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &num1,&num2,&num3,&num4))<4) /* used comma in between %d for comma check, but how to generate error if input is without commas. */
```

and how to identify prime number & how to implement the program using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bit of code is almost correct: you should check the returned value to know how many values were read by `scanf`.  But you should probably capture that return value in a variable so you can find out if it is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

As for how to identify a prime number, show us the code you've tried so far in a new question.  Likewise, multithreading is a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You first condition is fine , like if there is anything entered other than intger than `scanf` wont return `4` , so it will cover each case of wrong input .

But you need to check vairables to find out what it contains.